# Is there a good technique for cooking chestnuts?

Tags: chestnuts

I would like to make my own puree and would like to know of any ways that might be recommended for cooking them first.  I tried the oven once and they started exploding: Ideas?

Comment: Over an open fire? ;-)

Comment: Roasting on an open fire - right around the corner, buddy :>)

Comment: I hope you got video of the exploding chestnuts!

Comment: Neil: Nope, but it did scare the heck out of me - sounds like a gun shot!!

Comment: Yes it does sound like a shot. Darn it, my oven was clean. Was.

Answer (score 14):

If you are going to cook chestnuts, you need to score them first. Most commonly, they're scored in an X pattern -- try to do it on the side away from the flattest side. Make sure you cut all the way through the shell. Then as they cook, the shell will actually peel back slightly as they cook. Here's a [link](http://startcooking.com/blog/299/How-to-Roast-Chestnuts) with pictures about baking them. (425 degrees until they're done, 20 to 30 minutes.)

For certain recipes, you can also boil them. According to [this website](http://startcooking.com/blog/299/How-to-Roast-Chestnuts), you can boil them for about 3 minutes and then peel them. You then will need to finish cooking them in your recipe. Or you can boil them in the shell for 15-20 minutes. This will lead to them falling apart -- which may be appropriate for a chestnut puree.

Still another method I found is to cook them in oil, as described [here](http://nutgourmet.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/cooking-and-peeling-chestnuts/). Cook for 5-10 minutes, stirring constantly.

Comment: In my experience you just can get away with a single deepish score across the chestnut (as you say) on the bulbous (less flat) side of the chestnut. Also expect a few 'dead' chestnuts sometimes.

Comment: I was just told that if you nick them slightly at the top and soak for a few hours prior to boiling, this will help...

Comment: I also score them with a single cut over the top.

Comment: Had to come back and thank Martha. I read this a month or two ago and just tried it yesterday. I've always scored (cut an X on) the flat side, because that's what my parents did. But scoring the rounded side was much easier - the nut stayed still - and they were substantially easier to peel - the shell curled back further from the meat. I cooked them at 375 until they smelled like roast chestnuts, though I understand that wouldn't help a first-timer. I love chestnut season!

Comment: Glad it worked! Now I just need you to invite me over for some chestnuts! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I've been baking Italian chestnuts for years. Holding a chestnut between my forefinger and thumb, I make two long scores on the chestnut in the shape of a "+" on the bulbous (rounded) side of the chestnut about a tenth of the way through using a paring knife with my opposite hand. I then place them on the middle rack of a preheated oven (500F degrees) on a cookie sheet or stainless steel dish for 10 to 15 minutes, depending on the size of the chestnuts. *They come out perfect every time.

I've found making a large shallow "+" is better than a single deeper slice, it makes them easier to peel once cooked and less dried out.

*There are "dead" ones from time to time, but this seems to happen less with Italian chestnuts than domestic (US) ones.

Comment: It is always a pleasure to be the very first upvote for a brand new user. Welcome to Seasoned Advice.

Answer (score 4):

You can do them in the oven, in a skillet on an open fire, etc.  The secret is properly slitting the shell so that is does not explode.  They have moisture inside and will pop/explode like popcorn if you don't slit the shell.

Comment: The scoring is a pain if you're doing a few dozen, but if you don't, you *will* get the resultant chestut shrapnal everywhere.  And after you pull it out of the oven, they'll continue to explode from carry-over cooking.  (luckily, I was wearing my glasses at the time).

Comment: @Joe A cook wearing glasses being attacked by exploding chesnuts...  It's a good thing you made survived; it would have been a pity to have the tombstone read:  _But for the carry-over cooking, he would have made it._

Comment: You can actually buy [knives][1] specifically for scoring chestnuts. They've got short, curved [blades][2] and are meant to make it easier. I've never tried one, since I have enough specialized tools in my kitchen already and I only make chestnuts once or twice a year. 

[1]: http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-chestnut-knife.htm
[2]: http://www.chestnutsforsale.com/Chestnut-Knife_p_29-17.html