# How to peel chestnuts?

Tags: roasting, peeling, chestnuts

The [chestnuts on an open fire](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8937/how-to-roast-chestnuts-on-an-open-fire) question reminded me: Is there a trick to peeling chestnuts easily? I always end up with bits of hairy skin stuck to the chestnuts (ick), and/or stuck under my fingernails (ouch). We usually roast them in the oven (after slitting them suitably, of course); is there a cooking method that results in easier peeling?

In case it matters, I'd want the chestnuts either for eating out of hand, or for making chestnut puree.

Comment: Related : [Is there a good technique for cooking chestnuts](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5590/is-there-a-good-technique-for-cooking-chestnuts)

Answer (score 5):

My experience has been that the freshest chestnuts can be peeled pretty easily if I do it while they're still hot (I usually roast them). This does mean that one's fingers can get burned, though! I wonder whether some of the recommended techniques for peeling garlic cloves would help with "sticky" chestnut-skins? [Choosing fresh chestnuts over moldy ones is a problem in itself; off to see if there's a question about that!]

Comment: +1. The "secret" is that supermarket chestnuts aren't fresh. Go to a good-quality Chinese market for fresh chestnuts.

Comment: I use a dishtowel to handle and peel them, when very hot, and this reduces most of the burning but my thumbs are usually very sore when I am done. It's worth it though!

Answer (score 5):

I have just shelled & peeled a kilo (forty ounces) of chestnuts in 20 mins using the following method. cross cut the chestnuts, six at a time. Microwave dry on full power for 30 secs. The outer shells and skin will then have opened out where cut. Squeeze the still hot nut between thumb & forefinger, this further loosened the inner skin. I then found that the shell & skin were easily removed and the kernel came out whole in one piece.

Ray Newall. North Wales.

Comment: I'll have to try this. Thanks for the detailed description!

Answer (score 2):

I was told but I never tried, so try this at your own risk

Put the chestnuts in microwave (yes the whole chestnuts with outer skins) for 30 seconds. The skin should crack open and the hairy skin will come off nicely.

Please don't vote me down if this sounds stupid and I will remove this.

Comment: I did this a number of times and it works. I did score the outer skin, though.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the uncut in microwave 30 seconds...a few worked a few blew up...but what a laugh we had doing it...I’ve researched and tried anything you can name but I think the answer is much simpler than that, I buy my stuff at supermarket and I think it’s just they are not fresh enough...I’ve seen people scoring the chestnut with a sharp knife I’ve had to use a a sharp knife and a hammer..my skins are rock hard..I’ve read the best place to buy them is Chinese supermarkets..so I’ll try that next...good luck all..